# Python 2.x to 3.x converted code fails in IO.StringIO conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

python 2.x code

```
sdata = StringIO.StringIO(c.data)
```

python 3.x code

```
sdata = io.StringIO(c.data)
```

complete code

```
def downloadCSV(c, d):
    filename = c.getFilename(d)
    reqstr = c.getReqStr(d)

    print(("Downloading %s ..." % (filename)))
    if c.getResponse(reqstr) == -1:
        return -1
    sdata = io.StringIO(c.data)
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(sdata)
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 166, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "xxxx.py", line 158, in main
    getMonth(c, args[1], args[2])
  File "xxxx.py", line 133, in getMonth
    if downloadCSV(c, d) > -1:
  File "xxxx.py", line 73, in downloadCSV
    sdata = io.StringIO(c.data)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

right import is done for 3.x python version and the conversion for sdata should be automatically happening here ? Why this above error coming ,and what is the way to correct this error in python3.x . Tried other answers posted in this forum but nothing seeming to be working in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 now makes a difference between `str` and `bytes`.

Your request returned binary data, so to be able to store it in a `io` object you have to create a `BytesIO` object not a `StringIO` object. So:

```
sdata = io.BytesIO(c.data)
```

Note that the code is still compatible with Python 2.